# How to make python 2.7 print ({}).format(utf8string)

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

in Python 2.7.12 I want to print a utf-8 string:
The following works:

```
l = u'übermäßig'
print l
übermäßig
```

The following does not work

```
l = u'übermäßig'
print ("{}").format(l)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I spent some time ...
Could anyone please tell me how I can use utf8 strings in formatted printing?
So much appreciated

Comment: Does `print u"{}".format(l)` work?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

This should solve your problem:

```
print u"{}".format(l)
```

Alternatively, I suggest you add

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

to the top of all your scripts.
Or switch to Python 3.
Both will save you quite some pain in the future...

#### Explanation

... because the `str`/`unicode` type mixture is quite tricky in Python 2.
I see that there is already a bit of confusion in your post: `u"übermäßig"` is not a UTF-8 string – it's a `unicode` string.
You might be using UTF-8 to encode your source  code, but when the Python interpreter parses this literal, it converts it to an object that doesn't have to care about the encoding anymore (be it UTF-8, UTF-16, Latin-1 or whatever).

In many cases, you can freely mix the `str` and `unicode` types.
If you type

```
"{}" + u"übermäßig"
```

then Python will upgrade the (byte) string `"{}"` to `unicode` before concatenating the two objects.
This is called implicit coercion.

However, in the case of

```
"{}".format(u"übermäßig")
```

you are using the `format()` method of the `str` type, and coercion doesn't take place.
Instead, the `str.format()` method forces its argument to be converted to `str`, ie. it has to "downgrade" `unicode` to `str`.
It's the same as calling `str(u"übermäßig")`, which requires *encoding* the Unicode string.
And the default codec in this situation is ASCII, which can't handle "ü", "ä", or "ß".

In contrast, `u"{}".format(u"übermäßig")` uses the `unicode.format()` method, which (of course) requires an argument of type `unicode`.
By using the `unicode_literals` pragma mentioned above, all string literals `"..."` are interpreted as if they had been written `u"..."`.
This is what you want in most cases; if you actually need a byte string, write `b"..."` instead.
That's how Python 3 works, too.